# SQL Deleting from multiple tables in different databases without common elements

Tags: java, sql, db2

What I have are 7 tables, one of which is a master list and the other 6 are archives. Also, the archives are on another database. I need to go through the archive tables and delete rows, by checking 3 different column IDs (top, middle, bottom) that are not listed in the master table, as they are not relevant anymore. My SQL statement is below. I don't have a way to test it yet, but since I am not very familiar with SQL I was hoping people could give a few tips.

```
       String[] tables;
        tables = new String[]{"archive1", "archive2", "archive3", 
                                  "archive4", "archive5", "archive6"};

        String query;
        Statement stmt;
        String objs = "TOP AND MIDDLE AND BOTTOM";
        while(i<tables.length){
            //TODO: CONFIRM THE QUERY IS CORRECT
            query = "DELETE FROM "+ tables[i] + " WHERE "+ objs +
                    "NOT IN(SELECT " + objs + " FROM DB.masterTable WHERE " +
                    objs + " IS NOT NULL)";
                    //IS NOT NULL may not be necessary
            try{
            //TODO: VERIFY CONNECTION IS CORRECT
                stmt = this.DB2.createStatement();
                stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            }catch(SQLException x){
                System.out.println("Failure in loop queries!");
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

In the tables there are many columns, but I am concerned with comparing the top, middle, and bottom IDs (together they are unique to each row, but e.g. top might have many of the same values). So like I said, if there isn't a row with the same TOP, MIDDLE, BOTTOM in the master table, OBJECTS, then that row can be deleted from the archive that has it listed. I tried to put everything in one query but maybe I need multiple?

My main questions are:
A) Is my query correct in any sense?
B) Since the tables are on 2 different databases how should I handle that?

Solution found:

```
       query = "DELETE FROM "+ tables[i] +
       " WHERE (TOP, MIDDLE, BOTTOM) NOT IN "+ 
       "(SELECT TOP, MIDDLE, BOTTOM FROM DB1.DB.masterTable)";
```

Main problem became figuring out how to compare all 3 fields of each row at a time and accessing the DB tables

Comment: Any reason you couldn't use a database link between the two instances. It would be much easier/more efficient to use a `NOT EXISTS` than to try fetching rows from one database and loop through them all to update the others.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe changing the databases will be allowed at all, how do they work exactly? Thanks

Comment: I definitely wouldn't recommend a shot in the dark when doing a DELETE! A db join would allow you to use data from both at the same time. Otherwise you will have to do a two step process; this is the fundamental problem with your solution. Using Java to do this is like using a stone to hammer in a nail, it'll work but your better off using a hammer (db/SQL) instead which was designed for the job. If the two databases are on the same physical host then a link shouldn't be a problem. How are rows moved to the archive in the first place?

Comment: @StormBringerX Lol very true that's why I'm trying to get an idea for the best way to do it :D The databases are on the same host, and my method will only be a part of a much larger program so I can't very well use another language/toolset. I am unsure exactly how the tables are updated. I will look into a DB join/link, but can I simply address the other table's database as shown above e.g. db2.table2?

Comment: If they are two separate JDBC connections then no; if they are a single connection and db2.table2 is visible then yes. I know DB2 calls Databases when they are just schemes so maybe they are visible between each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) No.  There are some fundamental errors in your query. If you expand out your query, where `objs = "OBJ_ID_TOP AND OBJ_ID_MIDDLE AND OBJ_ID_BOTTOM"`

```
query = "DELETE FROM "+ tables[i] 
        + " WHERE OBJ_ID_TOP AND OBJ_ID_MIDDLE AND OBJ_ID_BOTTOM 
              NOT IN(SELECT OBJ_ID_TOP AND OBJ_ID_MIDDLE AND OBJ_ID_BOTTOM 
                     FROM db1Connection.OBJECTS 
                     WHERE OBJ_ID_TOP AND OBJ_ID_MIDDLE AND OBJ_ID_BOTTOM IS NOT NULL)";
```

This is not proper SQL... If we take a glance at the wiki page on the [WHERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29) clause,

> The proper syntax for writing SQL Where clause is
>
> SELECT <> FROM table WHERE column operatorvalue

Use `AND` and `OR` to string up multiple column conditions in your `WHERE` clause.

Also, `AND` is not valid in a `SELECT` statement.  If you want to combine multiple result sets, use [UNION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#UNION_operator).

---

Something of the form (see below) is closer to what you need.  (Note: it is not optimized by any means... just a demonstration)

**EDIT** Think I originally misunderstood what you were trying to do... but I think you want to delete from `some_table`, not `master_table`.

```
--DELETE --can swap out SELECT for DELETE when the selected results look right
SELECT s.* 
FROM some_table s  --this is table[i]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN master_table mt   --db1Connection.OBJECTS
     on s.ID_TOP = mt.ID_TOP
        AND s.ID_MIDDLE = mt.ID_MIDDLE
        AND s.ID_BOTTOM = mt.ID_BOTTOM
WHERE mt.ID_TOP IS NULL
        AND mt.ID_MIDDLE IS NULL
        AND mt.ID_BOTTOM IS NULL
```

B) I can't help you with this question... someone with more DB2(?) chops can help you

Comment: From what I understand performance isn't a major concern, so I'll move more in your code's direction. Thanks for pointing out the SQL syntax issues, I'm still fairly new to this

Comment: Looking at your code, I don't think I need to check the other columns not the same as the NOT IN column right? I'm unsure why I would need to UNION with the other columns such as in the first NOT IN block: since I need to see if there's a reference to ID_TOP shouldn't it only need to then sub-select ID_TOP from table, not the ID_MIDDLE and ID_BOTTOM unioned with it? Thanks again

Comment: @RazrWire Edited my response. I thought you were matching one id as possibly matching ID_TOP, ID_MIDDLE, and/or ID_BOTTOM.  You don't need UNION after all since that's not what you're doing ;)

Comment: @RazrWire Think your alternative approach is close but you want the LEFT OUTER JOIN... RIGHT OUTER JOIN keeps all entries from the right table (which is the master table) but I assume you want to delete the extraneous archive records? ... in any case, using select first can show you what you're about to delete before you commit to it. And rollback if you decide you don't want to commit the deletion.

Comment: Thanks for your comments I think I found a solution that works, I'll add it in my post in case you or anyone else is curious

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to get the list of data to be deleted from the first DB.
2. Then go for deletion in the second DB

And, you just can't compare saying obj1 and obj2 and obj3 not in (some list), it should be like obj1 not in (somelist) and obj2 not in (somelist) and obj3 not is(whatever).

In this case, it would be a good idea to create a temp table in DB2 where the archive tables are, with data from the master table in DB1. Then, run queries like

```
delete from archive1 where col1 not in (select col_master from temp_table);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, for starters how would I get the list to be deleted since I need to compare the tables to find said list? Something like 'resultset = SELECT FROM table WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM archive); DELETE FROM archive WHERE EXISTS (resultset)'